# Angular Material: mat-error encapsulation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to encapsulate the `mat-error` into its own component since the text tends to be quite long. Therefore I thought about:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="title" placeholder="Title" required />
        <app-mat-error-too-long [ctrl]="form.controls.title"></app-mat-error-too-long>
     </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="ctrl.hasError('maxlength')">
    <span >Input too long</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>{{ctrl.getError('maxlength').actualLength}}/{{ctrl.getError('maxlength').requiredLength}}</span>
</mat-error>
```

with the component:

```js
    import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
    import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-mat-error-too-long',
      templateUrl: './mat-error-too-long.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./mat-error-too-long.component.scss'],
    })
    export class MatErrorTooLongComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() ctrl: AbstractControl
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

But if I do so the error is not displayed properly and is right under the component:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mat-error` needs to be used directly inside mat-form-field to work correctly. So what you can do is to use an attribute selector instead for your child component and attach it to `mat-error`:

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <input matInput formControlName="title" placeholder="Title" required />
   <mat-error app-mat-error-too-long [ctrl]="form.controls.title"></mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Then you need to of course remove the `mat-error` tag from the child and instead just show your messages. The child selector also needs to change, wrap brackets around it:

```
selector: '[app-mat-error-too-long]'
```

Comment: Just a stupid question: is it better to replace the `mat-error` by a `div` or by a `ng-container`?

Comment: not a stupid question. div is always a div, so it will display as a div in th DOM. `ng-container` is kind of an "invisible" element, it really doesn't exist in the DOM. So it is more css related which way to go :) In this case I'd go with ng-container, since that would mean that your template is identical to a "regular" mat-error in the DOM. But as said, style related more than anything :)

Comment: Works as expected - thx.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks for this, it was exactly the problem I was having! (I went with ng-container btw) `<ng-container>{{ errorText() }}</ng-container>`